# Xuggle codec identification fail

Tags: java, codec, xuggle

I'm trying to run the following [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/) code:

```
public static boolean convert(String stream) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(stream + ".flv");

  IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(stream + ".mp3", reader);
  reader.addListener(writer);

  while (reader.readPacket() != null)
   ;

  return true;
}
```

Where stream is the file path. But I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not find input codec id
 at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:393)
 at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:327)
 at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:300)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.addStreamFromContainer(MediaWriter.java:1141)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1046)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeAudio(MediaWriter.java:837)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onAudioSamples(MediaWriter.java:1448)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(AMediaToolMixin.java:89)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchAudioSamples(MediaReader.java:628)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeAudio(MediaReader.java:555)
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:469)
 at <package_name>MediaFile.convert(MediaFile.java:66)
 at <package_name>.MediaFileTest.shouldConvertExistingFLV(MediaFileTest.java:32)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The unit test is the following:

```
 @Test
 public void shouldConvertExistingFLV() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String str = "C:\\Program Files\\Wowza Media Systems\\Wowza Media Server 2\\content\\Extremists";
  boolean result = MediaFile.convert(str);
  assertTrue(result);
 }
```

So, why can't he find the codec, since I'm testing for a simple flv to mp3 conversion?

Comment: where u able to find the answer for this? I am stuck too

Comment: I didn't, my company back then changed to wowza.

Answer (score 0):

If your source is a true flv stream (no odd codec info) then this should work. There are only two problems I can think of that would arise here:

- There is not enough meta data info coming in before the writer starts to encode. For instance the codecs have not been detected.

  The incoming video is causing the failure due to its being invalid for the mp3 container type. Write a media tool to ignore the video.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The trick lies in creating in adding an audio stream on the Writer. This code snippet works for me in extracting an audio stream from a flv and transcoding it to an mp3.

```
     IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(filename + ".flv");
     IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(filename + ".mp3", reader);
     int sampleRate = 22050;
     int channels = 1;
     writer.addAudioStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MP3, channels, sampleRate);

     reader.addListener(writer);
     while (reader.readPacket() == null)
               ;
```