# Red 5 Generated FLV from live streaming and Xuggle

Tags: flash, streaming, flv, red5, xuggle

Im Using Red5 to record live stream from the user. I am able to save the stream to disk and it generates an FLV file.

1. When I'm trying to read the FLV file with some FLV player - it seems like the file's meta-data is corrupted - which also makes the progress bar to act oddly.
2. Also, I tried to play with the file using Xuggle. It seems impossible since the generated FLV do not have the codec-id in it.

Any insight will be much appreciated.

Here is my relevant Red5 (JAVA) code:

```
public void record(IConnection conn, String streamName) 
{
  ClientBroadcastStream stream = (ClientBroadcastStream) getBroadcastStream(
  conn.getScope(), streamName);
  try {
        stream.saveAs(streamName, false);
  } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
  }
}

public void encodeWithXuggler(IConnection conn, String streamName)
{
   String nm = "C:\\Program Files\\Red5\\webapps\\Red5Recorder\\streams\\"+
              streamName+".flv";
   File f = new File(nm);

   if (f.exists()) {

   IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(nm);

   reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeWriter("output.mov", reader));

   while (reader.readPacket() == null);

   } else {
       System.out.print("NOT EXiST");
   }

}
```

And the Xuggle error message I get:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null inputCodecId
 at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:295) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.addStreamFromContainer(MediaWriter.java:1141) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1046) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeAudio(MediaWriter.java:837) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onAudioSamples(MediaWriter.java:1448) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(AMediaToolMixin.java:89) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchAudioSamples(MediaReader.java:628) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeAudio(MediaReader.java:555) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]
 at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:469) [xuggle-xuggler.jar:3.4.1012]`

Comment: BTW - I did see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760570/xuggle-codec-identification-fail but Im not sure this is the same issue

Comment: For the meantime: The problem is not Xuggler - but the generated/encoded flv by Red5.

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed a bug with establishOutputCodecID, so you may want to try the current Xuggler tip of tree.